# ODBC SQLDescribeParam using MS Accees

Tags: ms-access, odbc

I'm using ODBC to connect to MS Access database saved in mdb file. Current code uses SQLDescribeParam function before binding query parameters, unfortunately odbc driver manager states that **default Access driver** on windows xp sp3 does not support this function.

```
ODBC_ERROR: IM001:1:0:[Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Driver does not support this function
```

Are there any other drivers built to connect to MS Access that support SQLDescribeParam?

Answer (score -1):

Why even bother with using query parameters? Just use the table name or query name direct.

```
strCity = "Edmonton"

strMySQl = "select * from myquery where city = '" & strCity & "'"

or use the table direct

strMySQl = "select * from myTable where city = '" & strCity & "'"

… your code here to open recordset.
```

The above is a TON less hassle fooling around with some query parameters that do absolute NOTHING to help your code, nothing to help you your maintains, and in fact using a saved query with parameters does not even save execute and  processing speed (in fact I can quote documents that show they run slower!!!).

So, just use the name of the query in your code and append your sql "where" clause as you need in code.  You save lots of coding time and hassles, and as noted you then not need to worry about obtaining the parameters of a query anyway. Just remove all the parameters from your query, they are a hassle and will only increase you IT budget as you waste time on something you don't need to do and something that will not yield you any practical benefits.

Comment: It says ODBC, so this could be a small website or public location.

Comment: Thank for your opinion, its not a small website, the product is actually biometric software solution. SQLBindParameter was chosen because ODBC does not provide argument escape function (like mysql). It aims to be correct rather then fast.